# $G$ has an abelian subgroup $K$ with $|K|\geq p^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^4$ for some prime number $p$. Suppose $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ of order $p^2$. Then $G$ has an abelian subgroup $K$ with $|K|\geq p^3$.

First, by acting $G$ onto $H$ by conjugation, I have an injection $G/C_G(H)\hookrightarrow \mbox{Aut}(H)$. Since $H$ is group of order $p^2$, I checked that whether $p$ is even or odd primes, $p\mid |\mbox{Aut}(H)|,p^2\nmid |\mbox{Aut}(H)|$. Since $G/C_G(H)$ is $p$-group, I concluded that $G/C_G(H) = 1$ or $\simeq \Bbb Z/p$. Now I want to say that $C_G(H)$ is abelian but stuck. Please help.

Comment: By the way, every group of prime power order $p^n$ has normal subgroups of order $p^m$ for all $m$ with $0 \le m \le n$, so you don't need to suppose that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^2$. It definitely does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group $T$ such that $T/Z(T)$ is cyclic, is Abelian (exercise). Now apply it to $C_G(H)$. This gives you what you want in case $C_G(H)/H$ is cyclic of order $p$. Now from what you proved, since $G/H$ is Abelian of order $p^2$ it handles the case when $G/C_G(H)$ is cyclic of order $p$. If this factor-group is trivial, then take any coset $aC_G(H)\in C_G(H)/H$ of order $p$ (it exists by Cauchy's theorem because in this case $C_G(H)/H$ is of order $p^2$). Since $a$ centralizes $H$, $\langle H,a
\rangle$ is Abelian of order $p^3$.

Comment: How can you pick order $p$ coset $aC_G(H)$? $G/C_G(H) =1$.

Comment: @love_sodam: If $G=C_G(H)$ then $C_G(H)/H$ has $p^2$ elements, so it has an element of order $p$ (Cauchy).